# How can I git rollback/redo working dictionary files within one branch like a snapshot?

Tags: git, rollback, git-commit, snapshot, git-checkout

I only has one git branch (master), also it is a private repository (only used by myself). How can I easily rollback/redo my working dictionary files like snapshot management?

For example:

1. I commit 1st time, with only 1.txt in the dictionary
2. I commit 2nd time, to add 2.txt in the dictionary
3. I commit 3rd time, to add 3.txt in the dictionary

Now the question is:

1. what command I should issue for git to recover my working dictionary only include 1.txt file?
2. After above step 1, what git command I should  issue again to restore my working dictionary, let it has 3 files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt) again?

Basically I want to treat it as snapshot management for working dictionary to easily switch between different commit. Is it doable with git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a new branch: `git branch my_branch`
2. switvh to this branch: `git checkout my_branch`
   (1+2 in one step: `git checkout -b my_branch`)
3. reset the branch to the third-last commit: `git reset HEAD^^ --hard`
   (the count of '^' determines how many commit you go back)

no you can switch between the states by checking you either 'my_branch' or 'master' respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So we still use git branch, right? Without branch, we cannot really switch backward or forward.

Comment: well, you can checkout certain commits without a branch. But you would need to deal with commit IDs.  I strongly suggest to use self explaining branch names or at least *tags*.

Comment: Thanks for great help!